# Is there a published XSD describing Apache NiFi template XML?

Tags: xml, xsd, apache-nifi, xsd-validation

I am storing NiFi templates in XML format within a repository that is continuously deployed. While most changes to the templates in this repository are replacements of the file, sometimes it's significantly faster to make changes manually within the XML.

I would like to automate a validation of the template files to ensure that I haven't done something silly to inadvertently break a template. The first step of this is validating that the file is valid XML. That's pretty easy! The next step would be validating it against an XSD schema.

Looking through a locally-built NiFi, I see some XSD files:

```
$ fd xsd
nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-authorizer/src/main/xsd
nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-authorizer/src/main/xsd/authorizers.xsd
nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-file-authorizer/src/main/xsd
nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-file-authorizer/src/main/xsd/authorizations.xsd
nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-file-authorizer/src/main/xsd/legacy-users.xsd
nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-file-authorizer/src/main/xsd/tenants.xsd
nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-framework-core/src/main/resources/FlowConfiguration.xsd
nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-web/nifi-web-security/src/main/xsd
nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-web/nifi-web-security/src/main/xsd/login-identity-providers.xsd
nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/test/resources/TestXml/XmlBundle.xsd
```

I looked through these a bit and only `FlowConfiguration.xsd` really struck me as a candidate. It includes a schema of `template` elements but is scoped to `flow.xml`.  I could *probably* extract only the parts relevant to `template` but it'd be more convenient if that already exists!

**Does an XSD that describes only NiFi *templates* exist?**